# Как с помощью RxJS положить значение в переменную?

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, async-await

Есть функция:

```js
getData (id: number, objectId: number): Observable<ObjectData | undefined> {
  let res$;
  if (!this.objectData.length) {
    this.loadObjectData(id)
    .subscribe((objectData) => {
        res$ = objectData.find((i: ObjectData) => i.id === objectId);
      },
    );
  } else {
    res$ = this.objectData.find((i: ObjectData) => i.id === objectId);
  }
  return of(res$);
}
```

как мне сделать так, что при условии `if (!this.objectData.length)` функция дожидалась выполнения загрузки и помещала значения в переменную `res$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно присваивать значение в переменную, а сразу верните `Observable`, а чтобы преобразовать данные используйте pipe и метод [.map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map).

```
getData(id: number, objectId: number): Observable<ObjectData | undefined>{  
    if (!this.objectData.length) {
      return this.loadObjectData(id).pipe(map((objectData) => objectData.find((i: ObjectData) => i.id === objectId)
  ))
    } else {
      return of(this.objectData.find((i: ObjectData) => i.id === objectId));
  }
}
```

В таком случае, вам не нужно ждать, когда закончится подписка. А все ожидание будет уже там, где будет вызван метод getData